# Java interface synthetic method generation while narrowing return type

Tags: java, inheritance, jvm

I have 2 interfaces, and 2 return types.

```
interface interfaceA {
   Publisher<String> doSomething();
}

interface interfaceB extends interfaceA {
   Flow<String> doSomething();
}

interface Publisher<T>{}
class Flow<T> implements Publisher<T>{}
```

So at runtime, I can see 2 methods of `interfaceB.class.getMethods()`

1. `public default my.package.Publisher my.package.interfaceB.doSomething()`
2. `public abstract my.package.Flow my.package.interfaceB.doSomething()`

Regarding the first one, it is Synthetic. `(method.getModifiers() & 0x00001000 > 0) == true`

Does java autogenerate this synthetic methods?

How does it work in general?

Comment: Those things are called bridge methods. They are needed because for the JVM the method type consists of all arguments and it's return type.

Comment: Possibly related: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

Comment: For a very in-depth talk about bridge methods you can watch this Video with Dan Heidinga and Brian Goetz: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOBHtmqavXc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here is called a bridge method.

To understand why this is needed, we have to look at how the JVM determines if two methods are different:

- Every method has a name. Different name -> different method.
- Every method has a descriptor. Different descriptor-> different method.

The descriptor contains all arguments and the return type (with generics, it's erasure).

From the JVM perspective `Flow doSomething()` is a different method than `Publisher doSomething()`, so when it is asked to do a invokeinterface call to `Publisher doSomething()` it won't call `Flow doSomething()`.

This can happen if the target at the callsite is of type `interfaceA`:

```
intefaceA foo = ...;
foo.doSomething();
```

But from the language perspective, both methods are the same, and one overrides the other.

To restore this relationship, `javac` adds a bridge method with the original method type that just calls the overloaded method.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html) specifies the following:

> A construct emitted by a Java compiler must be marked as synthetic if it does not correspond to a construct declared explicitly or implicitly in source code, unless the emitted construct is a class initialization method

Another definition I've seen from [Java Papers](https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-synthetic-class-method-field/) is:

> When an enclosing class accesses a private attribute of a nested class, Java compiler creates synthetic method for that attribute.
>
> EDIT: It was pointed out that some of what this article states applies to an older Java version (SE7), so be mindful when reading online papers.

So for example:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Synthetic {

  public static void main(String[] arguments) {
      Synthetic.NestedClass nested = new Synthetic.NestedClass();
      out.println("Age: " + nested.age);
  }

  private static final class NestedClass {
      
      private String myName = "Tom";

      private int age = 42;

  }

}
```

The compiler will create synthetic methods for every private attribute being accessed. So, it'll create synthetic method (`static int access$000(Synthetic$NestedClass)`) for `age`, but not `myName`

Comment: This example won't create any synthetic methods with Java 11+.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the default constructor is *not* synthetic. So starting with JDK 11, this example will indeed not have synthetic members. This answer is wrong anyway, as it says that “`NestedClass` will be marked as synthetic” whereas only the generated accessor method would be marked. And the linked paper’s statement “If there is a getter method available in source then this synthetic method will not be created” is wrong as well, as the compiler will not convert a field access to a getter call.

Comment: @Johannes, regarding your statement about Java 11, I ran two tests. In the first I complied the code with Java 8 and then used the Java class file disassembler (`javap`) on `Synthetic$NestedClass.class`  and for `NestedClass age` to de-complies to create `static int access$000(Synthetic$NestedClass);`. If I run the same steps but using JDK 11, the result is exactly the same. so in essence it is creating a synthetic method to access `age` (even it seems with Java 11).

Comment: @Holger, I can see how the statement about the getter is confusion. Did some reading on this as I've have seen that before and it turns out that it was something occurred in SE7. Similarly regarding what is marked as synthetic. Will just update the answer above accordingly. Tx (TIL)

Comment: It’s not clear why you still have the synthetic method in JDK 11. Did you use a `-target` or `--release` option, resp. an IDE setup for an older version or Eclipse’s compiler? I just verified that with the right setup, there are no synthetic accessor methods in Java 11. This also applies to the additional synthetic constructor of `NestedClass`.

Comment: @Holger, used the command line for this as I did not want to be unclear about the versions (incidentally I prefer using intelliJ IDEA, not Eclipse). Had JDK 11 setup and checked everything was correct with `-version` (11.0.3) before running the tests. Then setup JDK 8 and did the same (1.8.0_202). What version of Java 11 are you running?

Comment: _java 11.0.3 2019-04-16 LTSJava(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)_    .... and ....    _java version "1.8.0_202" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)_